# Load different template for each custom post types in a page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I create some custom post types and each CTP have a different template.
i use this code in each CPT

```
add_action( 'template_include', array(&$this,'output_template'), 1 );

public function output_template( $template_path ) 
{
global $wp_query;
if ( get_post_type() == $my_CPT_name ) {
$template_name = 'single-'.$my_CPT_name.'.php';
}
return $template_path;
}
```

i have a page and i want to show some of different CPT inside this page.
unfortunately the get_post_type() return "page" instead of CPT-name because these CPTs are called inside a page :(
is there any way to detect each CPT type and call templates according to each one.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving custom post types data somehow. So, why not just pass the CPT name as a variable?

Comment: Hi webmogul, thanks for your reply. Sorry how can i do that( passing variable to function that i used in "template_include")?